# SimpleMappingExceptionResolver not Resolving 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, modelandview

Below is my spring configuration file:

```
<bean class="com.web.handler.CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver" >
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>              
            <prop key="java.lang.Throwable">error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Class `CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver`

```
public class CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver{
    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {

    if(int a = 1)
        return new ModelAndView("ViewName1");
    else
        return new ModelAndView("ViewName2");
    }
```

My `web.xml` has no error page. I am looking to show different view according to my logic in `resolveException()`.

In `CustomSimpleMappingExceptionResolver` class `resolveException()` is not being called in case of 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set error page in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

your error page will redirect as soon as it opened.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=error.htm">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

There should be a request mapping in your controller to handle error.htm request.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/error.htm"})
    ModelAndView routToErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
//any logic for your themes
}
```

Comment: Redirection gives a HTTP Status code of 404. Does spring do the same ?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration might be incorrect; [use a map](http://developingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/03/09/handling-exceptions-in-spring-mvc-part-2/) instead of properties.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
<property name="exceptionMappings">
  <map>
    <entry key="DataAccessException" value="data-error" />
    <entry key="com.stuff.MyAppRuntimeException" value="app-unchecked-error" />
    <entry key="com.stuff.MyAppCheckedException" value="app-checked-error" />
  </map>
</property>
<property name="defaultErrorView" value="general-error"/>
</bean>
```

Also, I'm not sure SimpleMappingExceptionResolver handles errors thrown when finding a handler but rather it handles errors thrown from inside handlers. That said, I'm not sure 404 can caught this way.

If you put a error handler in web.xml that will go back into your servlet where you can handle it any way you like.